# Searching text, returning multiple word matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a search for particular words in a message table containing the columns ID, Message

I am currently using a case of the form

```
select message_table.id, 
    case 
    when message_table.message like "%word1%" then 'word1'
    when message_table.message like "%word2%" then 'word2'
    when message_table.message like "%word3%" then 'word3'
    end as Filter
from message_table where Filter is not null
```

If a row in the Message column has the value ;word1,word2,word3; only one is returned currently.

I would like to have them all instead. Thought a concat/group concat might help but not quite sure how I would go about producing a row for each word found.

Would appreciate any advice!

EDIT:
All solutions provided look good, will have to try them all and see which has the best performance. My current query already takes longer than I'd like it, will come back in a bit with result

Edit2: The winner speed wise is (even faster than my case above).

```
select id, group_concat(word)
from
   (
   select id, 'word1' as Word from message_table where message like "%word1%" union
   select id, 'word2' from message_table where message like "%word2%" union
   select id, 'word3' from message_table where message like "%word3%" 
   ) alias
   group by 1
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return separate rows for each word, the easiest way is to essentially make three queries and lump them together with UNION:

```
SELECT id, 'word1' FROM message_table WHERE Filter IS NOT NULL AND message like '%word1%'
  UNION
SELECT id, 'word2' FROM message_table WHERE Filter IS NOT NULL AND message like '%word2%'
  UNION
SELECT id, 'word3' FROM message_table WHERE Filter IS NOT NULL AND message like '%word3%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your output needs, something like this should work using `CONCAT`:

```
select message_table.id,
    concat(
       case 
          when message_table.message like "%word1%" then 'word1'
          else ''
       end,
       case
          when message_table.message like "%word2%" then 'word2'
          else ''
       end,
       case
          when message_table.message like "%word3%" then 'word3'
          else ''
       end)
    as Filter
from message_table
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/40e0f/4).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a join:

```
select mt.message_table_id, words.word as filter
from message_table mt join
     (select 'word1' as word union all select 'word2' union all select' word3'
     ) words
     on mt.message like concat('%', words.word, '%')
```